# What is the best way to move game objects, smoothly rather than teleporting it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move a game object, pokemon, from the centre of the screen to the left of the screen (only along the horizontal axis), smoothly. However, it keeps teleporting instantly.

**WHAT THE CODE DOES** = Changes from one sprite to another sprite in an endless loop. When it changes to another sprite, it also changes its scale.

**WHAT I WANT THE CODE TO DO** = Before changing to a different sprite, move left on the horizontal axes.

I have tried linear interpolation (lerp) and transform.translate.

```
public class Transitions : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Sprite Pokemon_0; // VARIABLES FOR SPRITES (Pokemons/ game objects) 
    public Sprite Pokemon_1;

    float timer = 1f; // CHANGING SPRITES VALUES (delays)
    float delay = 5f;

    Vector2 temp;     //CHANGING POSITION VARIABLES
    Vector2 tempPos;
    Vector2 finalPosition;


    void Start()
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Pokemon_0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        if (this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite == Pokemon_0) // TO CHANGE FROM POKEMON 1 TO POKEMON 2 
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Pokemon_1;

            temp = transform.localScale;  // TO SET THE SCALE WHEN EACH POKEMON CHANGES (works)
            temp.x = -380;
            temp.y = 350;
            transform.localScale = temp;
            timer = delay;

            finalPosition = new Vector2(167, -107);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, finalPosition, 1f * Time.deltaTime);

            //tempPos = transform.position; // Tried and tested method. Doesn't work. 
            //tempPos.x = 1f;
            //transform.position = tempPos;



            return;

        }
        if (this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite == Pokemon_1) // TO CHANGE BACK FROM POKEMON 2 TO POKEMON 1
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Pokemon_0;
            timer = delay;
            return;

        }

    }
```

On execution, this code does change pokemon and changing the scale. However, the position remains the same.

I am open fairly new so I'm constantly trying our different suggestions, thanks.

Comment: You definetly should use Lerp for this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: Could you please post a minimal reproducible example? I guess in this case it will be at least the whole class code.

Comment: give it a rigid body and force?  adding 1 unit may also bee a bit much as its going to add 1 per frame.. if you get 200fps, it will fly by

Comment: Is that code in the `Update()` method ?

Comment: @eocron just tried using the link you shared. Turns out that the gameobject just stays still. Posting whole class code now.

Comment: @BugFinder Tried. It just moves the game object smoothly downwards off the screen.

Comment: @HSN720 the short answer is not using deltatime will mean a less smooth move.. a rigidbody will mean it will move without updates,however, its also effected by gravity , and you need to apply the right force for weight to get the speed and if theres drag the speed will drop as it goes..

Comment: @DmitriyPopov Hi, just posted the whole class with explanation of what it does. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: If you want to post an answer to the question then *post an answer*, rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use a tween engine , like http://dotween.demigiant.com/.

If you install Dotween then you can simply use

```
transform.DOMove(new vector3(1 ,0 , 1) , duration);
```

You can also set Ease for tweens. or use Oncomplete fucntions;

```
transform.DOMove(new vector3(1 ,0 , 1) , duration)
    .SetEase(Ease.OutCubic)
    .OnCompelete(() => { shouldClose = true; });
```

You can also set loop for your tween `.SetLoops(-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code example, it appears you are using the position's x value differently. The x y and z values are used together to form a point, which is represented in the 3D environment. Settings the object's position to the previous position it had while changing the x value to 1 each time will lock it on the horizontal axis.

You can use either interpolation to smooth out the transition between two position states or use Unity's built-in Vector3.MoveTowards (or Vector2 if in a 2D landscape).

**Interpolation**

Your desired position is the exact position you want to change to. Your current position will be `transform.position`.

```
float step; // Set this to how fast you want to increment movement (1f, 5f, 10f)
Vector3 start; // Set this to the transform.position when you want to start interpolating
Vector3 desired; // Set this to a new Vector3(x, y) with the place you want to move to

void Update(){
    // Here, we set the object's position to it's current position, but interpolated to it's desired position
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(start, desired, step * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

**MoveTowards**

```
float step; // Set this to how fast you want to increment movement (1f, 5f, 10f)
Vector3 desired; // Set this to a new Vector3(x, y) with the place you want to move to

void Update(){
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desired, step * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Hi, just tried both of your methods. Unfortunately, they didn't work for me. It appears as though they don't do anything. My sprite stays in the same place. I just updated the post with my whole class and explanation of what the code does, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Lerp takes start and end point, not current and end point. It should also have a way to reach 1 at some point. MoveTowards is set to perform extremely small movements.

Comment: @Everts Thanks, I've updated the answer.
As long as the sprite is on a GameObject with the script it should work. If that doesn't seem to do anything, try changing the step variable to something larger

Comment: The problem with lerp in that way is that the object will move fast at first and slow down towards target and as it gets closer it will move really slow. This is because the movement is each time a fraction of the remaining distance. So it acts as a limit. What is needed is to increase the ratio so that it reaches 1 and finalizes the movement.